# Turn off ads for jobs

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Is there a way to turn off ads for jobs?

Essentially the job ads that come up at the side of the page in the form of: Are you currently looking for a job? etc...

I mean these ones and the corresponding orange ones with the 'Are you looking for a Job?' title.

[image: BlueJobAds]

[image: OrangeJobAds]

Comment: I don't think there's a setting anywhere, but they'd be easy enough to adblock (`#hireme`).

Comment: If you feel weird about that, Stack Overflow has publicly stated that they don't care if you use an ad blocker:https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/

Comment: I use Stylish to do the same. It's there but I can't see it `#hireme { display: none;}`

Comment: It's not that I want to block all ads on the site, just the jobs ones as I'm not looking and don't really want to for a while

Comment: @Ana I've updated with a screenshot of the blue one

Comment: Actually I'm really interested in the jobs ads. I'm only passively looking for opportunities but continually seeing job offers that don't meet my requirements just makes the whole ads block useless noise. 
This block should be more like a stream where new ones are shown until I mark them as seen. As it is currently I rather use some ad-blocker to get rid of them even though I'd be really interested in matching ads.

Comment: I also have to add that the block didn't show a single jobs ad that matches the tags I selected. They are all for tags entirely irrelevant to me.

Comment: @Ana - Any progress on this? I'd like to no longer see job-related ads. I'd be fine with different ads in their place.