# Option to hide job ads. Too much space taken

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I found it hard to believe that after obtaining the reduce ads privilege I would still saw the obnoxious ads on every question page I visit.

The left side of featured on meta was the question, ***Notice the scrollbar:***

[image]

[image]

**It took so much space** to see the linked and related stuff of the question and answer.

The setting doesn't seem to do anything:
[image]

And therefore I propose to have the ads at the very least collapsible or had the option to be turned off.

Related: [Turn off ads for jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328008/turn-off-ads-for-jobs), [I don't want to see anything about jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340187/i-dont-want-to-see-anything-about-jobs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: How do you expect SE to get money to run the service if you can hide *all* the ads?

Comment: For me adds usually only take up ˜40% of screen height. Nothing obnoxious there....

Comment: @Raedwald How useful is it to advertise jobs to those who aren't interested?

Comment: @Luuklag That settles it then, nothing wrong here. Can we close this and move on?

Comment: Greasemonkey + custom user script = no ads

Comment: @Raedwald Ads continue to be one of the _worst_ ways to get money from users. If they're that broke, they shouldn't turn to unreliable and increasingly useless ads.

Comment: [Why Stack Overflow Doesn't Care About Ad Blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/) - They are actually OK with you blocking ads you'll never click on.

Comment: For those think I want to hide all the ads: To be honest I don't really want to hide them all the time. But at the very least to have the option to hide/show them at will would help on the User Experience when navigating. What's so bad with giving the option rather than turning user to used script to hide?

Comment: I never understood these questions. We have uBlock, but even if that wouldn't be the case, we are programmers... What prevents any of us blocking it with an extension or a userscript? Seems to be a smaller effort than writing a question.

Comment: Seems like a flawed argument to me. Are you expecting no improvement when there is something to improve?

Comment: I don't believe there is an argument to not improve things.  I think some are arguing that giving there are ways around it, and the microcosm of S.O. is filled with programmers of some flavor, the priority to do so isn't that high.

Answer (score 31):

The job ad, along with other sidebar ads, is not covered by the Reduce Ads privilege. Also, if hiding the job ad becomes a setting/privilege, it probably wouldn't do well for it to be on the same setting as Reduce Ads, as that might confuse people who want job ads but not banner ads, or vice versa.

---

Here's some workarounds for the meantime (with the standard limitations):

- Bookmarklet:

  ```
  javascript:(function(){$("#hireme").hide()})();
  ```
- Console snippet (<kbd>F12</kbd>):

  ```
  $("#hireme").hide();
  ```
- Userscript:

  ```js
  // ==UserScript==
  // @name          Stack Overflow - Remove Obnoxious Job Ad
  // @author        a stone arachnid
  // @namespace     https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/
  // @version       1
  // @match         https://stackoverflow.com/*
  // ==/UserScript==

  (function(){
      $("#hireme").hide();
  })();
  ```
- Adblock filter:

  ```
  stackoverflow.com###hireme
  ```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fancier user style for de-cluttering the sidebar *only on small screens*, which I kind of hope SO might some day adopt:

```css
/* for users with left sidebar enabled */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    html.html__responsive:not(.html__unpinned-leftnav) #sidebar > div:not(.module):not(#feed-link) {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* for users with left sidebar disabled */
@media screen and (max-width: 816px) {
    html.html__responsive.html__unpinned-leftnav #sidebar > div:not(.module):not(#feed-link) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The `max-width` media queries and the beginning of the selectors inside them are copied from the SO style sheet, and cause these styles to only apply on screens where the sidebar is moved below the main content.  (Nobody ever scrolls down there anyway, unless they *really* want to see the linked questions, so it's unlikely that SE would lose any ad revenue by adopting these styles.)

Note that this style also hides the yellow box with links to blog and meta posts.  If you'd like to keep it, append `:not(.s-sidebarwidget__yellow)` to the selector(s).

(Conversely, if you'd like to *always* remove ads and the yellow meta box from the sidebar, even on wide screens, you don't need all that fancy CSS above; a simple `#sidebar > div:not(.module):not(#feed-link) { display: none }` will do.  Add `#sidebar > #hot-network-questions { display: none }` if you also wish to hide the HNQ sidebar.)